# average of marks using an array – entered by user with certain time

Tags: c, arrays, timer, average

Would like to ask your help!! 
I have difficulties in adding timer, in finding average marks. 
The marks will be entered by user at specific time. 
i.e. Every one minute, user will enter the marks.
1st minute -enter the 1st value

wait for another 60seconds, then

2nd minute -then enter 2nd value. 
3rd minute- then enter 3rd value.

so every nth values that will be entered by user is 60seconds difference.

I have added every one minute countdown but the output gives weird value after i enter num=5.

Code below is added one minute timer:

```
printf("Enter the marks to find average: ");
            scanf("%d",&num);//get input from user

   // for num, i enter 5, so num=5 then 5 values should be entered  
    // time taken for entering 5 values will be 5 minutes. 

                //loop for get input from user
                for(i=0; i<num; i++)
                { 
                 timer++; 
                //if timer is equal to 60 then, get 1st mark from user, 
                 if (timer ==60)
                 {
                    printf("Enter marks %d: ",i+1);
                    scanf("%f", &arr[i]);
                }
                timer=0; //reset back to zero and loop again to get next marks! 
                }
```

full code including timer and finding average values  as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
        int main()
        {
            float arr[100];//array declaration-keep max to 100 
            int i,num;//variable declaration
            double avg=0.0,sum=0.0;
            static uint32_t timer = 0;   //1min timer for getting marks 

        printf("Enter the marks to find average: ");
        scanf("%d",&num);//get input from user

//if user enter "10", then 10 values should be entered 60secs apart. 
// time taken for entering 10 values will be 10minutes. 

            //loop for get input from user
            for(i=0; i<num; i++)
            { 
             timer++; 
            //if timer is equal to 60 then, get 1st mark from user, 
             if (timer ==60)
             {
                printf("Enter marks %d: ",i+1);
                scanf("%f", &arr[i]);
            }
            //timer=0; //reset back to zero 
            }
            for(i=0; i<num; i++){ //loop calculating sum of array elements
                sum=sum+arr[i];
                avg=sum/num; //calculating average
            }
            printf("Average of entered numbers are: %.2f",avg);
            getch();//display result on the screen
            return 0;
}
```

output as attached[image]

Comment: Please show your exact input and output. A few things to note though they are probably not the cause of your problem: 1. You only need to calculate the `avg` once after the final `sum` has been calculated and not on every loop. 2. Incrementing a counter does not take 1 second so you are not really waiting for the amount of time that you have described (not sure if that's intentional).

Comment: That can't be your actual code because `timer=0` is commented out which means only one mark will be read. Please check whether you are showing the right version of your code.

Comment: @kaylum, thanks for reply. I am not sure how to add the one minute timer, anyidea? before we get the 1st data, wait 1min, then second data wait another 1mins, etc...

Comment: [man sleep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html)

Answer (score -1):

In your loop, the timer will be incremented only 5 times. Find the below correct code.

```
       for(i=0; i<num; i++)
        {
            printf("Enter marks %d: ",i+1);
            scanf("%f", &arr[i]);
            while(timer!=60) 
               timer++; 
            timer=0; //reset back to zero
        }
```

You can implement your application using timer functionalities.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-delay-c/